# Azure Cosmos DB check if array in field is contained in search array

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have an Microsoft Azure CosmosDB MongoDB Api database and I am trying to get all the documents where one array field is fully contained in my search array.

So, what I am looking for is, given the collection test containing the documents:
`{"id":1,"filters":[1,2]}
{"id":2,"filters":[1,3]}`

if I execute:
`db.test.find({"filters":{"$elemMatch":{$nin: [1,3]}}})`

I get back:
`{"id":1,"filters":[1,2]}`

However, if I negate it, since I want all the documents with filters fully contained in my search, the full list of documents is returned.
`db.test.find({"filters":{$not:{"$elemMatch":{$nin: [1,3]}}}})`

returns:

`{"id":1,"filters":[1,2]}
{"id":2,"filters":[1,3]}`

contrary to what is mentioned in the article:
[Check if every element in array matches condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23595023/check-if-every-element-in-array-matches-condition)

I also tried the $issubset on an aggregation , to no avail ( 0 results ) :

`db.test.aggregate([{$match:{$issubset:["$filters",[1,3]]}}])`

I even tried ( 0 results ):

`db.test.aggregate([{$match:{$issubset:[[1],[1,3]]}}])`

Anyone with an idea of what is happening her?

- Is it my error?
- List item  Am I using mongoDB features not implemented in CosmosDB yet?
- Is it CosmosDB bug?

Thank you!

Comment: Detailing a little further: I need the documents with all the elements in the filter array contained in my search to be returned. So even if the document has only a partial match but no matches outside of the search it should still be returned. adding this to the initial question...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a server error when testing $nin on my side. Then I tried to use $and to combine multi sub queries and it worked fine. Please using following code to query all the documents with filters fully contained in your search.

```
{ "filters": NumberInt(1), $and: [ { "filters": NumberInt(3) } ] }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, sorry for the late reply, it does not fulfill exactly what I was trying to explain:
I need the documents with all the elements in the filter array contained in my search to be returned.
So even if the document has only a partial match but no matches outside of the search it should still be returned.

adding this to the initial question...